# div not floating right

Tags: css, html

Why is the blue div not adjacent to green div?

This is the html. Nothing but containers with borders.

```
<div id="wrapper960"  style="min-height:350px; border:1px red solid">
<div class="content-sidebar-l" style="min-height:250px; border:1px yellow solid">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content" style="min-height:250px; border:1px green solid"></div>
<div class="content-sidebar-r"style="min-height:250px; border:1px blue solid"></div>

</div>
```

This is the CSS with centered div on the middle.

```
#wrapper960 {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:960px;}

.content-sidebar-l {
  float: left; 
  width:170px; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;}
.content {
  margin:0 auto; 
  padding:1em 0 0 0; 
  width:610px; 
  background-color:#fff;}
.content-sidebar-r {
  float: right;
  width:160px; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;}
```

[image: blue div floating right issue]
<sub>(source: [imagesup.net](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=7135585031013))</sub>

Here it is in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eYJaP/)

Comment: Please post a complete code example, HTML included.

Comment: Either you have placed the blue container after the green container, or the sum of your margins, outlines, borders and widths is greater than the width of the outer container.

Comment: The colours in your code are yellow, green, red and black. Which one is supposed to be the blue one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-order your HTML to:

```
<div id="wrapper960"  style="min-height:350px; border:1px red solid">
<div class="content-sidebar-r"style="min-height:250px; border:1px black solid"></div>
<div class="content-sidebar-l" style="min-height:250px; border:1px yellow solid">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content" style="min-height:250px; border:1px green solid"></div>
</div>​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TwJFe/)**

You need to float your sidebar to the right first, otherwise by placing it last it can't float up above an element before it that is also floated.

Answer (score 1):

You have no code that would allow the blue div to bubble up beside the green div.

e.g.

```
.content { float: left; }
```